# How can I pass catched errors in prepared for segue method?

Tags: swift, xcode

The view loads, checks something and the check will fail and throws an excpetion which in turn will be catched as the example shows. In this case I want to show an error view via segue. How can I transfer the catched errors via prepare segue method?
The only idea I have ist to store errormsg,errorMsgDetail into class properties. Is there a more straight forward way?

```
 override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        do {
            try CheckAndCopyDatabase(filename: "test.db");
            
        } catch ApplicationError.configurationError(let errorMsg, let errorMsgDetail) {
        
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueStartup2Exit", sender: self);
            
        } catch {
        }
    
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueStartup2Begin", sender: self);
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        
        if segue.isKind(of: segueStartup2Exit.self) {
            
            if let vc = segue.destination as? ViewControllerExit {
                
                vc.errorMsg = <--- errorMsg
                vc.errorMsgDetail = <--- errorMsgDetail
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance variable errorStuff:

```
var errorStuff: (errorMessage: String, errorDetail: String)?
```

Set the instance variable in your catch block before invoking `performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`. Then in your `prepare(for:sender:)` method, fetch the values you your tuple and pass them to the destination.